# Update field inner join

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

If i run this query i am getting an error:

What do i do wrong?

Query:

```
UPDATE cscart_profile_fields.value
SET    cscart_profile_fields_data.value = '0'
FROM   cscart_profile_fields_data
   INNER JOIN cscart_user_profiles
     ON cscart_profile_fields_data.object_id =  cscart_user_profiles.profile_id
WHERE  
where  cscart_user_profiles.user_id = 5316 and
(
cscart_profile_fields_data.field_id = 65
or
cscart_profile_fields_data.field_id = 66)
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM cscart_profile_fields_data INNER JOIN cscart_user_profiles ' at line 3
```

Comment: there is two "where" clause. remove one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:::

```
UPDATE cscart_profile_fields_data
       INNER JOIN cscart_user_profiles
     ON cscart_profile_fields_data.object_id =  cscart_user_profiles.profile_id
SET    cscart_profile_fields_data.value = '0'

where  cscart_user_profiles.user_id = 5316 and
(
cscart_profile_fields_data.field_id = 65
or
cscart_profile_fields_data.field_id = 66)
```

Comment: I am getting this error:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM cscart_profile_fields_data INNER JOIN cscart_user_profiles ON c' at line 3